# Stablecoin Development

Tags: solidity, blockchain, stablecoins

Can anyone link me with some information on how to develop stablecoins that are fiat backed, I can't seem to find anything on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

A stablecoin (in its simplest form) is a regular ERC20 token that is backed by a stable currency (usually USD). "Developing" a stable coin is mostly acquiring the necessary funds and getting attestations to that fact, then minting and distributing the equivalent amount in your stablecoin.

So from the Ethereum development side, it's simply an ERC20 token. There are a ton of resources out there about how to deploy one of those!

And then from the funds side, you'd probably want to speak to a lawyer about that. [USDC](https://www.centre.io/usdc) is a pretty well-respected stablecoin, and you can see their attestations [here](https://www.centre.io/usdc-transparency).

Comment: I didn't ask what it was, I asked how do you code something like a stablecoin. And eth is not the only blockchain where you can build a stablecoin on anymore.

Comment: You're on the Ethereum StackExchange. I gave you the answer to how to code a stablecoin: implement an arbitrary ERC20 and show folks that it is by some assets. It would be useful to folks trying to help you if you nicely added more information or gave more context :)

Comment: @Axel You received the perfect explanation - learn how to ask better questions (and perhaps to say thanks, instead of arrogantly criticizing). If you're thinking about algorithmic stablecoins, then look into DAI's whitepaper.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for developing stable coin and it depends on how you want to support and peg your stable coin, for example you can deploy an simple ERC20 token mintable & burnable (to doing this you can use openzeppelin contracts) then deploy simple Dex which able to swap your stablecoin with an pair like ETH or anything you want, Then you need some tokens as a backed token. when supply increased by users you need to buy your tokens with your liquidity(backed assets) and keep price of your token on a pegged price.

It is just one of ways for stable coin, as i said there are many ways to do this.